# Can we use multiple ul elements instead of multiple li elements inside a single ul?

Tags: html, css

I found out in HTML and CSS you can do what ever you want, so right after this question keep appear in my head and I haven't found an answer for it.

Mostly people will use a single ul for a nav bar like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Llamas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pajamas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Avocados</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

but what if I replace every li with a single ul like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul><a href="#">Home</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#">About</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#">Products</a>
        <li><a href="#">Llamas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pajamas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Avocados</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Why do I need list items when I can create a ul and, whenever I need to, just put an item into it?

However, As soon as I tested it, everything messed up, the body just sticks next to the nav bar and it so hard to fix.

Is this the reason no one uses it, or is there some other reason?

Comment: `a` elements are not valid direct child elements of `ul` elements. And from a semantic point of view it doesn't make any sense what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can use everything you want ! but it's not good for SEO and good parsable by spiders. it's better to have good html structure And follow that rules.

Comment: "_in HTML and css you can do what ever you want_" that's actually not true. There are specs for all HTML elements defining what can children an element can have. For instance, you can't have a `ul` inside a `p` like `<p><ul><li></li></ul></p>` - the browser will restructure that to ~ `<p></p><ul><li></li></ul><p></p>`. For your specific use case, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul lists `Permitted content`, and only those elements are allowed as children

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this for several reasons:

1. If you validate your HTML, you will see that an `<a>` isn't allowed to be a direct child of an `<ul>`
2. From a semantic viewpoint, you have four different lists if you do this, while your navigation should only be one list.
3. Why *should* you do this? While there are more cons then pros, I'm asking you what do you expect as a benefit?

---

To clear it out, imagine if you are blind and need to use a screen reader, you have the nav-tag and four different lists; even your whole nav list should be one list at all.

Comment: Furthermore, a list should have more than one point. And "list" something so it isn't useful to just declarting one thing as a list of something.